# How to format a generated multiplication table

Tags: tables, macros

I can create a multiplication list thought this code, but I have no idea how to format it to be aligned and usable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\def\sz{11}

\begin{document}

    \foreach \b in {1,...,\sz}{%
        \noindent%
        \foreach \a in {1,2,...,\sz}{%
            \pgfmathparse{int(\a*\b)}%
            ${\pgfmathresult}$ -
        }

    }

\end{document}
```

Right now it just looks like

[image: ugly tabel]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: numbers]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\def\sz{11}

\begin{document}

    \foreach \b in {1,...,\sz}{%
        \noindent%
        \foreach \a in {1,2,...,\sz}{%
            \pgfmathparse{int(\a*\b)}%
            \makebox[2em][r]{${\pgfmathresult}$}
        }

    }

\end{document}
```