# L3 Multiplication Table 1

Tags: expl3, xparse

In my `l3` adventures I looked at the post [How to format a generated multiplication table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453086/10898) and am pretty sure it can be done using `l3` implementation. While doing my research I found @egreg post on [Addition and Multiplication Tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210753/10898) and looked at his code regarding defining a new integer value and increasing it.

Is it possible to create a similar command in `l3`?

Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\shcmultiplicationtable}{m}
 {% #1 is max value of multiplication table
  \shc_make_multi_table:n { #1 }
 }

%\NewDocumentCommand{\shcmultiply}{ m m }       % does the multiplication that is desired           
% {
%  \fp_eval:n{ #1 * #2 }
% }

\int_new:N \l_shc_first_number_int
\int_new:N \l_shc_second_number_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \shc_make_multi_table:n #1 
 {
    \int_set:Nn \l_shc_first_number_int { 0 }
    \int_set:Nn \l_shc_second_number_int { #1 }

    \int_step_inline:nn {#1}
    {
    \int_incr:N \l_shc_first_number_int
    \fp_eval:n{ \l_shc_first_number_int * #1 }
    }

 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\shcmultiplicationtable{4}
\end{document}
```

So how can make the code below in `l3`?

```
\def\sz{11}
\foreach \b in {1,...,\sz}{%
    \noindent%
    \foreach \a in {1,2,...,\sz}{%
        \pgfmathparse{int(\a*\b)}%
        \makebox[2em][r]{${\pgfmathresult}$}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nest two `\int_step_inline:nn` cycles:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\multiplicationtable}{m}
 {
  \noindent
  \int_step_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \int_step_inline:nn { #1 }
     {
      \makebox[2em][r]{ \int_to_arabic:n { ##1*####1 } }
     }
    \int_compare:nF { #1=##1 } { \\ }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\multiplicationtable{11}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first `\int_step_inline:nn` cycle is for building rows, with base entry `##1=1`. The index here has to be named `##1` because it's at the “second level”. Each cycle has a nested `\int_step_inline:nn` cycle that builds the cells in the row; here the index has to be named `####1`, because we're at the third level. The number of `#` tokens before the parameter number is 2<sup>*n*–1</sup>, because in each level a macro with arguments is built; at higher level when the macro definition is performed, each pair of `#` tokens becomes a single one.

In each cell we can compute the required value using `\int_to_arabic:`, which expects an “integer expression” as its argument.

At the end of the outer cycle I add a test whether `#1=##1`, that is, we're or not at the last row; in case we aren't, add `\\`. This avoids the warning one gets when `\\` appears before an empty line.

---

A different implementation using `tabular`, where the table body is built in advance, making it easier to add “ornaments”.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,array}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\multiplicationtable}{O{2em}m}
 {
  \azetina_multiplicationtable:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__azetina_multiplicationtable_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \azetina_multiplicationtable:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__azetina_multiplicationtable_tl { $\times$ }
  \int_step_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__azetina_multiplicationtable_tl { & ##1 }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__azetina_multiplicationtable_tl { \\ \hline }
  \int_step_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__azetina_multiplicationtable_tl { ##1 }
    \int_step_inline:nn { #2 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l__azetina_multiplicationtable_tl
       {
        & \int_to_arabic:n { ##1*####1 }
       }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__azetina_multiplicationtable_tl { \\ }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{ @{} r |@{}  *{#2}{w{r}{#1}@{}} }
  \tl_use:N \l__azetina_multiplicationtable_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\multiplicationtable{11}

\bigskip

\multiplicationtable[1.5em]{4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Amazing how the `\int_step_inline` works. Thus, once `#1=##1` is false it will skip a line right? Let me see if I can add the header with the `\times` in the left corner like the table you created in the previous example.

Comment: @azetina Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: I am trying to get the header for the row and column `\times` for first row and column  `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11` but I cant seem to get the logic on how you did it in your previous example.

Comment: @azetina I added a slightly different implementation to add a top row and a left column.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. On another note, I noticed you have `\tl_set:Nn \l__azetina_multiplicationtable_t` but no `\tl_new:N \l__azetina_multiplicationtable_t`. Am I missing something that am failing to understand?

Comment: @azetina Forgot it.